# With, or without "the"?

Tags: definite-article

> 1. She's sitting in seat number eight.
> 2. She's living in room number two. / in flat two.

**Are the sentences incorrect with "the" (the seat / the room)? Why does one say them without "the"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'The' is the definite article. We use it when referring to things that all the people in the conversation know about, or that have a definite unique sense.

Your sentence implies the other person does not know the seat mentioned, and you are giving new information about the seat in question. Same for the flat/room. The word number is also implying that the seat/room/flat in question are so indistinguishable from each other - as in they have so little definition- they must be given numbers to identify them.

Thus you can use the article 'the' in the sentences given, if they are changed to: 'in the eighth seat' or 'the second room' in order to give these places a more definite sense.